# Show total and one subcategory in facetted stacked bar plots

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I know how to show all facets of subcategories of a dataset, but how can I show only one facet/subgroup along with the total? (Example taken from [r-cookbook.com](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Facets_%28ggplot2%29/))

```
library(reshape2) # for the tips data
library(ggplot2)
sp <- ggplot(tips, aes(x=total_bill, y=tip/total_bill)) + geom_point(shape=1)
sp + facet_grid(. ~ sex)
```

returns the following image:

[image: Two facets]

Now I want the left (right) facet to display the entire dataset and the other facet shall stay as it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
library(reshape2) # for the tips data
library(ggplot2)
sp <- ggplot(tips, aes(x=total_bill, y=tip/total_bill)) + geom_point(shape=1)
sp + facet_grid(. ~ sex, margins=T) #margins=True will add the total
```

**NOTE**

Using facet_grid there is no way to isolate only some of the facets along with the total. To do this check the update.

**UPDATE**

In order to replicate what you would like to do with the facets you would need the gridExtra library and do the following:

```
library(reshape2) # for the tips data
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
sp <- ggplot(tips, aes(x=total_bill, y=tip/total_bill)) + geom_point(shape=1) + ggtitle('All') 
sh <- ggplot(subset(tips,sex=='Male'), aes(x=total_bill, y=tip/total_bill)) + geom_point(shape=1) + ggtitle('Men') +
        theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(), axis.ticks.y=element_blank(), axis.text.y=element_blank())

grid.arrange(sp,sh,nrow=1,ncol=2)
```

[image: with gridExtra]

Comment: Thanks for the `margins=TRUE` option. That's already half the solution. On the other hand: Your two facets Male and (all) are identical. (all) does not include the Female dots.
Also, there are good reasons to avoid `subset()`, set [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/in-r-why-is-better-than-subset).

Comment: Yeah you were right. This is the only way to achieve what you need but it involves another library. Hope it helps. I think this is the only way. Check the update.